# Using attr.ib() for class member variables

Tags: python, attr

I'm not well versed with Python (mostly use C++) and the `attr` module. I'm looking through my codebase at work, and I often see class attributes created as follows:

```
import attr

class my_class:
  first_member_var = attr.ib()
  second_member_var = attr.ib()

  def func():
    self.third_member_var = non_class_func()
```

In this class `third_member_var` was not set to `attr.ib()` like the first two. I'm not sure if the original developer just forgot to do this, or if there's some functional difference by doing this or not?

Comment: `attr` is not a standard Python module. Can you provide a link to the documentation?

Comment: I guess it's the one from www.attrs.org?

Comment: The first two are class attributes (somewhat like static member variables in C++), while the third is an instance attribute. It's hard to say what the original developer intended without more context.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.ib), `attr.ib()` doesn't do anything unless the class definition is decorated with `@attr.s`

Comment: If you are new to Python, I would not recommend using any library like this initially. Work through the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), learn about the difference between class and instance attributes, and maybe play with the dataclasses provided by the standard library before you start using this particular 3rd-party module.

Comment: @chepner It seems like they don't have that choice, since they're working with an existing codebase, not writing new code of their own.

Comment: So if you want to learn what this `attr` stuff is about, read the documentation at the above website.

Comment: Nothing I suggested couldn't be done in a side project before or while reading the code at work. Working on Python code without actually understanding Python isn't likely to lead to good results.

Comment: @Barmar yeah it's that one

Comment: @chepner ahh that's the confusion then. I didn't know the first two were solely class attributes. now this makes sense

Comment: @chepner I'm not that new to Python. Just don't use it often enough to know some of the intricacies like this. I have to work in this existing codebase that uses these modules but I think it's a good idea to work through some tutorials as well

Comment: Well, *initially* they are class attributes. As Barmer pointed out, those class attributes are intended to be processed by the `attr.s` decorator, which likely uses them to generate a `__init__` method that defines instance variables of the same names.

Comment: The `attr` module is a fancier alternative to the built-in `dataclass` module. The basic idea in both cases is that you define attributes at the class level and they automatically become instance attributes. It's analogous to the way you have to declare class members in C++.

Comment: @Barmar I see, but is it only for class attributes or also for instance attributes?

Comment: `dataclass` turns all attributes in the class declaration into instance attributes. `attr` allows you to be more selective.